# Splitting a LinkedList Object

Tags: java, oop, linked-list

I need to construct and return a new Q that contains that the second "half" of this Q.

Examples of what I'm trying to accomplish

- this Q before split:  1, 3, 4, 8, 14
- this Q after split:  1, 3
- new Q:  4, 8, 14

---

- this Q before split:  1, 3, 4, 8
- this Q after split:  1, 3
- new Q:  4, 8

class Q implements a Queue ADT using class LinkedList from the Java class library. Class Q below

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Q {

// all Q objects have the same default capacity...
private final static int DFLT_CAPACITY = 4;

// every Q object has the following instance variables...
private LinkedList<Object> ll;
private int capacity;

/**
* Constructs an empty Q having DFLT_CAPACITY.
*/
public Q() {
  this(DFLT_CAPACITY);
}

/**
* Constructs an empty Q having client supplied capacity.
*
* @param capacity switched to DFLT_CAPACITY if less than one
*/
public Q(int c) {
  capacity = c < 1 ? DFLT_CAPACITY : c;
  ll = new LinkedList<Object>();
}
```

My problem is that I need to return a Q object but I have a LinkedList. I know this attempt is completely flawed but Ive been stuck for awhile now.

```
public Q split() {
   int split = ll.size() / 2;
   for (int i = 0; i < split; i++) {
       ll.remove(i);
   }
   Q newQ = (Q) ll.clone();
   return newQ;
```

}

Comment: why do you not use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList(int,%20int)

Comment: *My problem is that I need to return a Q object but I have a LinkedList.* create a method in `Q` that modifies the LinkedList

Comment: What is `capacity`, and how is it "split" between the two Q's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) method of `LinkedList`.
***Note:*** Read the javadoc linked above, so you know how it works!

You'll also need a new (private) constructor to create the new Q object.

The following assumes that `capacity` remains unchanged for the existing Q object, and that the new Q object "inherits" the same capacity.

```
private Q(int c, LinkedList<Object> ll) {
    this.capacity = c;
    this.ll = ll;
}

public Q split() {
    List<Object> secondHalf = this.ll.subList(this.ll.size() / 2, this.ll.size());
    Q newQ = new Q(this.capacity, new LinkedList<>(secondHalf));
    secondHalf.clear();
    return newQ;
}
```